# Cálculo rápido de raiz quadrada e seu inverso multiplicativo em float

Tags: desempenho, matemática, float, números-mágicos

Ao conhecer o algoritmo "0x5F3759DF" (ou "fast inverse square root"), facilmente imaginamos um bruto número de variantes dele para calcular raiz quadrada e inverso multiplicativo dela em single-precision floating-point, cada uma com sua velocidade e precisão.

As vezes não compensam, como quando se tem inline intrínsecas que acessam instruções de máquina, mas há outras vezes que não há esse tipo de recurso e então esses algoritmos são úteis. Pode ser ainda que se conheçam maneiras ainda melhores de calcular esses valores.

Quais são os melhores algoritmos conhecidos de `sqrt` e `invsqrt` em termos de precisão e desempenho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introdução

Algoritmos derivados de `0x5F3759DF` começam usando os ditos "números mágicos" para em forma de inteiro formar o código binário  do `float` que aproximará a solução, podendo depois refinar a precisão com operações de ponto flutuante, normalmente utilizado o método de newton até três vezes (na maioria das vezes, só uma ou duas vezes).

Além disso, para ter melhor desempenho se deixa de tratar casos específicos (argumentos próximos de zero, negativos, nan, etc) e foca-se em casos mais comuns, reservando esses tratamentos à aplicação de acordo com as necessidades.

### Algoritmos sem aproximações refinadas

A forma mais rápida de calcular `sqrt` e `invsqrt` somente faz uma soma/subtração e um deslocamento de bits com o código binário do argumento em forma de inteiro (eu prefiro sem sinal), sendo assim muito rápido, porém pouco preciso.

O algoritmo a seguir calcula `sqrt` de um radicando (matematicamente, radicando é o argumento de uma raiz quadrada, cúbica, qualquer raiz em qualquer índice) com erro relativo abaixo de 3.475% em condições normais. Quando o radicando é zero, o resultado é 7.933e-20, resultando nesse mesmo erro absoluto neste caso. Por conveniência, vou assumir que a execução desse algoritmo leva um `sqrtTime`.

```
uint code=( 0x3F769E5C + *(uint*)&radicand )>>1 ;
return *(float*)&code ;
```

Já o seguinte calcula `invsqrt` de um radicando com erro relativo menor que 3.422%. Quando o radicando é infinito, o resultado é 5.239e-20, resultando nesse mesmo erro absoluto neste caso. Custa cerca de um `sqrtTime` mesmo.

```
uint code=( 0xBE6EC85F - *(uint*)&radicand )>>1 ;
return *(float*)&code ;
```

### Algoritmos com uma iteração de método de newton

De fato, erros relativos acima de 1% são inconvenientes. Devido a isso, ao menos uma vez se aplica sobre esses valores uma iteração do método de newton adaptado à função específica.

No caso da raiz quadrada, isso consiste em calcular `NewApproach=( OldApproach + Radicand/OldApproach )/2`, já no caso da inversa, `NewApproach = OldApproach*( 3 - OldApproach*OldApproach*Radicand )/2`.

Além disso, já que `[( √r1=Sqrt )]&&[( r2^(-1/2)=Sqrt )]=>[( r1=1/r2 )]`, também pode-se aplicar na inversa a fórmula `NewApproach=( OldApproach + 1/( Radicand*OldApproach ) )/2`, que é uma suave modificação do método de newton para refinar a raiz quadrada.

Sendo assim, temos a seguir um algoritmo de `sqrt` que tem erro relativo menor que 6.011e-4 e, segundo meus testes, custa pelo menos `2.8*sqrtTime`.

```
uint code=( 0x3F76CF5E + *(uint*)&radicand )>>1 ;
float root = *(float*)&code ;
return 0.5f*( root+radicand/root ) ;
```

Agora um algoritmo de `invsqrt` que tem erro relativo menor que 1.752e-3 e custa pelo menos `2.5*sqrtTime`.

```
uint code=( 0xBE6EB50D - *(uint*)&radicand )>>1 ;
float root = *(float*)&code ;
return root*( 1.5f + root*root*( radicand*-0.5f ) ) ;
```

E finalmente um algoritmo de `invsqrt` que tem erro relativo menor que 5.895e-4 e custa pelo menos `3.3*sqrtTime`.

```
uint code=( 0xBE6EB50D - *(uint*)&radicand )>>1 ;
float root = *(float*)&code ;
return 0.5f*( root+1/( radicand*root ) ) ;
```

### Algoritmos com duas iterações de método de newton

Normalmente, considera-se que mais de duas iterações têm custo/benefício alto, por isso vamos parar por aqui com as iterações. Com duas delas, percebe-se que as vezes é possível simplificar operações e também que `invsqrt` pode utilizar duas vezes uma das duas fórmulas ou utilizar uma vez cada. Se utilizar uma de cada, em questão de desempenho pouca diferença faz qual vem primeiro, mas a precisão é maior quando primeiramente se utiliza a mais precisa.

Temos a seguir um algoritmo de `sqrt` que tem erro relativo menor que 1.805e-7 e, segundo meus testes, custa pelo menos `3.9*sqrtTime`.

```
uint code = ( 0x3F76CF5E + *(uint*)&radicand )>>1 ;
float root = *(float*)&code ;
root += radicand/root ;
return 0.25f*root + radicand/root ;
```

Agora temos a seguir um algoritmo de `invsqrt` que tem erro relativo menor que 4.598e-6 e, segundo meus testes, custa pelo menos `4.3*sqrtTime`. Não se sabe a razão desse algoritmo ser mais lento que o anterior e, ainda assim, a retirada de uma iteração de cada um o torna mais veloz. Pode ser consequência de simplificações no outro.

```
uint code = ( 0xBE6EB50D - *(uint*)&radicand )>>1 ;
float root = *(float*)&code ;
root *= 1.5f + root*root*( radicand*=-0.5f ) ;
return root*( 1.5f + root*root*radicand ) ;
```

Agora, outro algoritmo de `invsqrt`. Este tem erro relativo menor que 5.213e-7 e, segundo meus testes, custa pelo menos `4.4*sqrtTime`.

```
uint code = ( 0xBE6F02E3 - *(uint*)&radicand )>>1 ;
float root = *(float*)&code ;
root = root+1/( radicand*root ) ;
return root*( 0.75f + root*root*( radicand*-0.0625f ) ) ;
```

E finalmente o último algoritmo de `invsqrt` com iterações. Este tem erro relativo menor que 1.737e-7 e, segundo meus testes, custa pelo menos `5.2*sqrtTime`. Percebe-se em relação ao anterior uma estranhamente enorme perda de desempenho e ínfimo ganho de precisão, o que torna este algoritmo menos recomendado.

```
uint code = ( 0xBE6F02E3 - *(uint*)&radicand )>>1 ;
float root = *(float*)&code ;
root = root+1/( radicand*root ) ;
return 0.25f*( root+4/( radicand*root ) ) ;
```

### Algoritmos com tabelas de números mágicos

Para finalizar, consideremos a possibilidade de refinar a precisão sem operações com `float` mas sim com uma seleção de distintas fórmulas na determinação do código binário via tabela de números mágicos em array. Pode-se fazer tabelas de diversos tamanhos, mas considera-se adequado o uso de tabelas com 1024 números inteiros sem sinal de 32 bits.

Os dois algoritmos a seguir que desenvolvi pegam uma parte do código binário do radicando e utiliza como índice de tabelas de termos próximos de `0x3F769E5C` e `0xBE6EC85F` (utilizados nos dois primeiros algoritmos, um de `sqrt` e outro de `invsqrt`) e também como índice de uma tabela de fatores que ajustam a derivada da função.

Repare que os fatores são usados num produto do tipo `Factor*CodePiece/2^32` que envolvem números inteiros de 32 bits, o que em bons compiladores é facilmente simplificado em proveito das instruções de máquina.

Primeiramente, o algoritmo de `sqrt` com erro abaixo de 2.008e-7 e custo de pelo menos `2.5*sqrtTime` segundo as medidas que fiz. Faz uso das tabelas `SqrtCodeTerms` e `SqrtCodeFactors`.

```
uint code=*(uint*)&radicand , piece=code&0x00FFFFFF , index=piece>>14 ;
code=( (uint)(( (int)SqrtCodeFactors[index]*(long)piece )>>32)+SqrtCodeTerms[index]+code )>>1 ;
return *(float*)&code ;
```

E o algoritmo de `invsqrt` com erro abaixo de 4.097e-7 e custo de pelo menos `2.7*sqrtTime`. Não se sabe a razão da diferença de desempenho com o algoritmo anterior. Faz uso das tabelas `InvSqrtCodeTerms` e `InvSqrtCodeFactors`.

```
uint code=*(uint*)&radicand , piece=code&0x00FFFFFF , index=piece>>14 ;
code=(uint)(( (int)InvSqrtCodeFactors[index]*(long)piece )>>32)+(( InvSqrtCodeTerms[index]-code )>>1) ;
return *(float*)&code ;
```

Para finalizar, essas tabelas foram obtidas por meio de um programa matemático da maplesoft. Com o maple, programou-se o código que calculava para cada índice os valores mais adequados para os algoritmos e esses valores foram impressos. As tabelas estão nos links a seguir.

Sqrt: [SqrtCodeTerms](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B1qrQLujHeX-meCDqMS133V6n5jsj4hW/view?usp=sharing) e [SqrtCodeFactors](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q9lz5LRWjbSykRiYMZQnYniTb6GC_Wj0/view?usp=sharing)
InvSqrt: [InvSqrtCodeTerms](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VqErCCJSa88QmQe_wEmrypYasunmPkB1) e [InvSqrtCodeFactors](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VXkY_LTFRDn8kPPg9Q35eybSBlnAcTKx)